# msbuild command not found in travis-ci

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget, travis-ci

I have the following travis file:

```
language: csharp
solution: src/LaraUI.sln
mono: none
dotnet: 3.0.100

before_install:
 - sudo apt install nuget

install:
 - nuget restore src/LaraUI.sln

script:
 - msbuild /p:Configuration=Debug src/LaraUI.sln
 - dotnet test src/Test/Tests.csproj
```

This gives an error saying that msbuild was not found:

```
msbuild: command not found
```

All the examples I see do not need to install anything, and msbuild/nuget just work. If I remove the line to install nuget, then I get a similar error of nuget not found.

Is there something I am missing in order to execute msbuild? Is there a way to install it?

The repository is [here](https://github.com/integrativesoft/lara)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use `dotnet build` instead of msbuild. It should do the same thing. Here https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build

Comment: sadly dotnet build does not work with NodeJS projects, only msbuild runs

Comment: @cat_in_hat Sorry that i answer this late i just saw your comment. Fortunately dotnet provides a way to also execute npm commands with dotnet build. Look at this for example ```<Target Name="client-app" BeforeTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <Exec Command="npm install" WorkingDirectory="client-app"></Exec>
    <Exec Command="npm run build" WorkingDirectory="client-app"></Exec>
</Target>```   If you add this to your csproj it should execute these commands on build.